# Threaded Comments, php, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**This is my table NewTheme_Comment:**

```
    id
    parent_id
    id_theme
    user
    text
    upVotes
    downVotes
```

**And this is my controller:**

```
class Comments extends Controller {

public function GenerateComments($id){
    $Comments = NewTheme_Comment::where('id_theme',  $id)->paginate(5);
    return view('comments', ['Comments'=>$Comments]);
}
```

**Id** is the link to the general post(each posts have different section of comments), so dynamically at the click of user, user is redirected to the ('comments view') section of comments accordingly.

So I have the array **Comments** which is populated with the values from the table NewTheme_Comment, the problem for me consists of how can I use the values to create a Threaded Comments section.

**Like so in my view(the problem is that this makes a comment section as like as every parent_id is equal to 0 which is not that I am looking for:**

```
 @foreach ($Comments as $Comment) {{-- Comments threads --}}

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <p class="media-heading">{{ $Comment->text }}</p>
    <p class="media-heading">{{ $Comment->user }} / {{ $Comment->created_at }} </p>
  </div>
</div>


@endforeach {{-- Comments threads --}}
```

**The end result:**

```
0 
1
2
3
2
1
1
0
1
0
```

My idea is to make comments like(with parent_id):

```
   0
     1
      2
       3
      2
     1
     1
   0
     1
   0
```

But I can't find the right way to do this thing logically, so that in the end to look like a simple threaded comment section the same that reddit uses( for my little web application ).

If my approach is bad, I would greatly appreciate other better ways on how to solve this.

Comment: You can group them by *parent_id* and then they will be structured correctly so you'll be able to output them nested.

Comment: How to group them by parent_id, like so (0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2 / 0,1,1,2,2,2) first branch and second one of a comment tree(2 single thread comment)?

Answer (score 2):

It is a multi-step solution. You should prefer using [lazychaser/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) package as the threaded comment is a form of nested set.

The other way round, if you want to continue with your current approach, will be having `child` function in your `Comment` Model, as follows

```
public function children(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment', 'parent_id'); //Change as per your application architecture
}
```

Then in views, you can check for the children of a given node by calling a partial view recursively, containing

```
//print the details of $Comment
@foreach($Comment->children as $childComment)
   //call this partial view again for $childComment & print the details
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

List every comment that doesn't have a parent_id, then when you load your comments check if any of those comments have childs comments and list those with indentation.